# ruby on rails form_tag with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

My view:

```
 <%= form_tag('filter', remote: true) do %>
      <%= label_tag(:q, "от:") %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:q, "", class: 'input.in') %>
      <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
 <% end %>
```

My controller:

```
def filter
    respond_to do |format|
       format.js
    end 
end
filter.js.erb:
alert(1);
```

I'm getting error in console `POST http://localhost:3000/filter 404 (Not Found) jquery.js?body=1:8707`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what you have written in routes.rb?

Comment: @user123, I have to? I didn't write anything, in tutorial there is nothing about routes, I thought that no need in ajax request for it. Correct me plz, if I'm not right

Comment: Your routes will be as: post 'filter' => 'controller_name#filter'

Comment: @AdnanDevops, Thank you. It works now, can you add it to andwers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your routes:

```
post 'filter' => 'controller_name#filter'
```